# How to find out if user is still logged in using session based authentication?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session

I know this has been asked countless times, but none of the answers I found described the actual connection to backend.

I have a one-page JS app that communicates with small backend (Django) API. I use session based authentication. User info is cached on first load. If session expires, I need to change page header and flush user info from cache. However, most of my API resources are public and return always 200. Several other resources are private and return 403 if user isn't logged in, which is great as this gives me excatly the information I need. The problem is, some pages access public resources only. In case session is suddenly deleted on backend and user navigates to url that accesses only public resources, user info isn't flushed and I have an UX problem.

My initial idea was to request private user resource (let's call it `/users/self/`) on every url change which returns 200 in case user is authenticated and 403 in case they aren't. This however requires 1 extra request before every other request for each url change, which isn't really ideal.

Are there any easier techniques I could use in this case? I don't mind even switching to other type of authentication if that would solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i have done and seen for such scenarios is to use some type of http interceptor that intercept all http requests done by Angular and if it finds a response status of 401, such interceptors raise an event using `$rootScope`.

See one library here https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth

To use it, one needs to subscribe to the events raise using some type of root controller, which can redirect the user to login page.

See an example here https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/7bbf0346acec

Comment: The problem is that most responses are public and always return 200. It wouldn't make sense for them to return 403/401 if session expired.

Comment: @OndrejSlinták don't mix routes on the server that need a session with open public routes. That's just going to create more work for you later.

Comment: What you are saying, is that the public responses are dependent on some restricted resource which means either they themselves should be restricted or in someway access the restricted resource which causes a authentication redirect on access.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini I'm not mixing those. Imagine you have user profile (public resource) which looks slightly differed when you have also access to friends (private resource). Profile itself is still public, but it changed depending on your authentication status.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sending a additional auth request, just check in your backend in every request, if the session didnt expire. If the user is not auth, then return a status code.

In angularjs we used a httpResponse interceptor, who intercepts every response and checks against this status code.

Comment: I cannot do this as some urls request just public resources which return always 200. It wouldn't make sense for them to return anything else.

Comment: but if you not logged in and request a resource, there must be a different reaction.

Answer (score 1):

We at work do what others have already told you: use an **HttpInterceptor**.

We have every response sent from our backend structured in the same way: an object with two fields: a *responseCode* and the actual *response*. We vary the responseCode according to what happened in the backend, being success, security alert, or authentication required for that given action the most common cases.

Then the interceptor reacts in the appropriate way according to each responseCode we have defined. In the case of an authentication required, we redirect to the login page, you could do whatever you need. It's working great for us.

Answer (score 1):

Your backend could add a header to the response if the user is still logged in, regardless if the requested resource is public or not. The client can then check the presence of that header and act accordingly.

On both sides this is done with some kind of filter or interceptor. In angular this would be a [$http interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http#interceptors).

Comment: I was thinking about this, but that would make response caching bit harder. But that's just my particular case.

Comment: @OndrejSlinták Could you please elaborate on your concerns? I don't see how this can affect caching.

Comment: In my case, I'm caching full responses, including headers. This way I'd have to alter them before sending the response. But it's still something I'm considering.